# How do you change a PNGs content in Python?

Tags: python, image, file, image-processing, overwrite

So I am currently working on a little program that is supposed to show me, whether RTX 3000 GPUs in Founders Edition are available in the NVIDIA Shop or not, by changing a picture and therefore its icon (on my desktop) to the RTX ON or the RTX OFF Logo. Therefore, the content of the image file has to be overwritten, but when I tried it like this:

```
import shutil
import os
desktop = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
with open(desktop + "\\RTX Availability.png") as indicator:
    if p["productAvailable"] == True:
            indicator.write("RTX_ON.png")
    elif p["productAvailable"] == False:
            indicator.write("RTX_OFF.png")
```

But I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\maria\PycharmProjects\RTX 3000 Stock Scraper\venv\Scripts\RTXScraper.py", line 28, in 
> indicator.write("RTX_OFF.png")
> io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable

But I don't know what else to do :(

Answer (score 1):

Haha, my bad, it should be:

```
with open(desktop + "\\RTX Availability.png", "w") as indicator:
```

And not:

```
with open(desktop + "\\RTX Availability.png") as indicator:
```